# Don't set POST request on api, get 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api, api-platform.com

Don't set POST request on api, get 406 Not Acceptable.
Tried to use axios and got 406 error. Was think that axios cause of the problem. Then I tried to use fetch() and got again 406 error.

I think that not seted header `Content-Type`, when I send his - get 400 Bad Request and in tab Preview `Unauthorized header content-type`.

Need your help, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks everyone for help.

- Environment: node v8.9.4, chrome 64.0.3282.119, Ubuntu 16.04
- axios version: 0.16.2
- Vue.js 2.4.2
- vue-axios 2.0.2
- api-platform/api-pack: 1.0
- Symfony 4.0.4

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBL80.png)
[Review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V69R6.png)

**First example fetch() code:**

```
const json = JSON.stringify({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
});
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/products', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: json,
});
```

**Second example Axios code:**

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
    data: this.cardData.brand,
});
const configAxios = {
    headers: {
     // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
};
axios.post('api/products', data, configAxios)
.then((res) => {
    this.cardData.brand = res.data;
    console.log(res);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.warn('error during http call', err);
});
```

Comment: Just uncomment the content type header? It should work.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu the fact of the matter is that it doesn't work.

Comment: It's a server problem. Your server returns `Content-Type: application/problem+json`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu tell me please, how can I send the correct `Content-Type` from the server from the api-platform?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution!**

Uncomment string in axios or fetch() code:

```
headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
```

If you use Symfony 4 as and am, setup `nelmio/cors-bundle`, run command `composer req nelmio/cors-bundle`. And configurate `nelmio_cors.yml`, namely add `allow_headers`.

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    allow_credentials: false
    allow_origin: []
    allow_headers: ['Content-Type']
    allow_methods: []
    expose_headers: []
    max_age: 0
    hosts: []
    origin_regex: false
    forced_allow_origin_value: ~
paths:
    '^/api/':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth', 'Content-Type']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600
    '^/':
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['^http://localhost:[0-9]+']
        allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth', 'Content-Type']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600
        hosts: ['^api\.']
```